# Compare TSV datasets for changes in database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, csv

I've got a dataset in TSV format put into a Postgres database using Java and Hibernate divided into multiple tables with around 30 million of entries in each table. Now periodically I receive the same dataset with some entries changed and some new ones added added in TSV format again.

It is not stated which ones have changed.

I want to find out which entries where added and changed and add the new ones and update the changed ones in the database. How would I achieve that without manually checking each entry?

Data comes from [IMDB database](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/) as:

```
tt0000177   1   The Burglar on the Roof US  \N  \N  \N  0 
tt0000178   1   The Cavalier's Dream    US  \N  \N  \N  0 
tt0000179   1   The Cave of the Demons  US  \N  \N  \N  0
```

Comment: That's a rather vague question. Is there a rule according to which the data are split up across tables? Do you get the dataset in a single file or split up? Perhaps you should add some samples.

Comment: Is there a 'primary key' for each data row in the TSV? Do the tables have primary keys and/or indexes on fields? One way or another you will have to touch each entry or it's index to determine this information.

Comment: I am using the [IMDB dataset](https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/)

Comment: Data is structured like this:
`tt0000177 1 The Burglar on the Roof US \N \N \N 0
tt0000178 1 The Cavalier's Dream US \N \N \N 0
tt0000179 1 The Cave of the Demons US \N \N \N 0`